# AMD GPU Pro on Loki (Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.4)

Tags: kernel, elementary-os, amd-graphics

I have R9 380 Tonga Chipset which is one of the GPUs AMD GPU Pro supports and since Loki is powered by 16.04 I thought it would work no problem.

I was following the guide from the AMD website

[AMD's Guide](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)

When I got to the install part I got "Unsupported OS".

I am a new low tier PC consumer to Linux. Do y'all know a way I can get this to work? Maybe Cassidy James has some other paternal barrier that I haven't by passed yet?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
        elementary)
            PACKAGES="amdgpu-pro amdgpu-pro-lib32 amdgpu-pro-dkms"
            ;;
```

to the `amdgpu-pro-install` file, right under the ubuntu part:

```
        ubuntu)
            PACKAGES="amdgpu-pro amdgpu-pro-lib32 amdgpu-pro-dkms"
            ;;
```

The install script failed to install some dependencies in my case, so I had to run `sudo apt-get -f install` in order to install them.
The amdgpu-pro drivers **didn't worked very well**, so I uninstalled them after testing. Maybe someone knows more about this topic.